# Inserting Opportunities using dataloader

Tags: opportunity, data-loader, insert

I am trying to insert opportunities using data loader. I have mapped all the fields correctly and all my accountid and ownerid are correct. Now when I am inserting, the job is failed and I am getting the error as 
"insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 001j000000E7xlw

I have the system administer profile.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the OwnerId to those of users other than yourself? If that's the case, do those users have the permission to create or own opportunities under the Account IDs in your file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even I have set the OwnerId to myself. Even then I am getting the same error. I have a system administrator profile.